# Voltage clamp for car

Tags: arduino, voltage, voltage-regulator

I designed this but when I start the car Arduino **resets**:

[image]
For voltage drop problem I decide to use Zener diode to clamp input voltage (8 V) and skip noise while start the car. I have some questions about second design:

**1- Is this design prevent Reset in Arduino?**

**2- If I add another high current module like Sim800 (2A) to MP1584 may I face current problem because of zener diode?**

**3- If it is not good do you have any idea?**
[image]

Comment: Is your shift key broken?

Comment: 1. No. 2. Yes. 3. Yes.

Answer (score 3):

Your Arduino likely requires more current than can flow through R1. A lower value of R1 will cause high current to flow in the zener and it will overheat.

You need a regulator that can accept the full range of the automotive battery (which is 9-16 V normally, but 24 V or 40 V under some faults and exceptional conditions).

Comment: but in datasheet i found : Wide 4.5V to 28V Operating Input Range for regulator

Comment: @yeganehhp but what is the current rating?

Comment: @Solar Mike MP1584EN support 3A ... All things like SIM800 works great . Just ARDUINO reset when i start car engine.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you're actually connecting 1584 directly to battery, is that correct?

If so, I read from 1584 datasheet a certain enable voltage hysteresis. If this pin is connected to vBat through resistor network like the typical Application, then the en voltage could fall below this threshold, thus deactivating vout and arduino

Comment: yes. I  connect it directly to battery ... What is your suggestion ?

Comment: You could add a capacitor between vin and ground, that will keep the voltage up for a brief moment when this kind of phenomena happens. I would say hundred of uF, but try several values

Comment: i will check it today ... Thank you

Comment: whats about floating EN pin ? I disconnect it and let input enable always ?

Comment: Leaving pin floating doesn't ensure it always enabled...unfortunately it would be just floating